Connect to Azure SQL with Managed Identity through azure function on app service plan
My current situation is this:

i've created a function app "func-test-01" (hosted on an app service plan) and it has authentication enabled through an app registration "appr-func-test-01"
i've deployed on it an azure function with an HTTP trigger with Authentication "Function"
After the deploy i've created a system assigned managed identity for the function app (its name is the same as the function app so func-test-01)
the azure function is supposed to create users on dbs provided through http body. In order to do this the connection string is created with this schema: $"Server={data.ServerName}.database.windows.net,1433;Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;Database={data.DatabaseName}"; that should leverage the managed identity (i suppose).

In order to call the AZF:

i first generate a token with appr-func-test-01 credentials
prepare the azure function call header with bearer authentication and the token generated
call azure function endpoint with the key function, providing the header and the necessary body

the call seems to work correctly (the function is callable)
The proble is inside the azure function.
In order to be able to perform the user creation task, i need to crete the "func-test-01" user (the function app managed identity) on each database!
If i do this on a target database:
CREATE USER [func-test-01] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [func-test-01];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [func-test-01];
GO
GRANT CONTROL TO [func-test-01]
GO

and call the azure function, it works as expected.
So far so good but we have many databases and planned to add the managed identity ("func-test-01") to the AAD group that is the owner of the server that hosts databases: if i do this operation, and remove the managed identity user from the database, i receive an error saying the service principal (the manage identity) is not able to connect to the database!
On the other hand, if i create another function app with consumption plan, without authentication, if i follow the same steps above (deploy, create the system assigned mi, and register it as member of the group that is the owner of the server), it works without the creation of the database user: what am i missing?

Finally i was able to let this infrastructure works, but there are some considerations:

i've created a service principal from app registration "appr-func-test-01"
i've added the service principal to database admin AAD group as the managed identity func-test-01
most important: you need to stop and restart the function app. For what i've understood, when the azure function try to connect to the database with the manageg identity, it asks for a token. This token remains valid (or invalid) till expiration so if at the time of request the azure function was not able to connect, it remains unable unless you allow it and restart the function app.

So, now, i'm able to connect to each database under the server without creating a managed identity user on each.
